# Creating nodes from nested JSON using neo4J query

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm new in neo4j and i have this json file:

```
{
  "locations_connections": {
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": "aws.us-east-1",
        "longitude": 72.8777,
        "latitude": 19.0760
      },
      {
        "id": "aws.us-east-2",
        "longitude": 126.9780,
        "latitude": 37.5665
      },
      {
        "id": "aws.us-west-1",
        "longitude": 103.8517837,
        "latitude": 1.287950
      }
    ],
    "connections": [
      {
        "aws.us-west-1": [
          {
            "id": "aws.us-west-1",
            "latency": 3.16,
            "cost": 0.02
          },
          {
            "id": "aws.us-east-1",
            "latency": 53.47,
            "cost": 0.02
          },
          {
            "id": "aws.us-east-2",
            "latency": 53.47,
            "cost": 0.02
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "aws.us-east-1": [
          {
            "id": "aws.us-east-1",
            "latency": 3.16,
            "cost": 0.02
          },
          {
            "id": "aws.us-east-2",
            "latency": 53.47,
            "cost": 0.02
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "aws.us-east-2": [
          {
            "id": "aws.us-east-2",
            "latency": 53.47,
            "cost": 0.02
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After reading the json using the apoc.load.json(URL) procedure , what query do I write to represent this as a graph?

where the Node will contain the information name like for example aws.us-east-1, value of longitude and value of latitude and the edges will have the latency and the cost

I have this code:

```
call apoc.load.json("/file.json") yield value
UNWIND value.locations_connections.locations as loc
UNWIND value.locations_connections.connections as con
MERGE (e:Element {id:loc.id}) ON CREATE
        SET e.longitude = loc.longitude, e.latitude = loc.latitude
WITH con
FOREACH (region_source IN KEYS(con)|
        FOREACH (data in con[region_source]|
                MERGE (e1:Element {id: region_source})
                MERGE (e1)<-[:CONNECT]-(e2:Element {id:data.id, latency:data.latency, cost:data.cost})        
))
```

and the execution result is incorrect:
Added 9 labels, created 9 nodes, set 27 properties, created 6 relationships, completed after 60 ms.and I have seen this one,But this is not what I expected

[image]

Comment: try it first then we will help if you get stuck. it is more fun on doing it rather than asking for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it, but unfortunately I only get nodes without links, and links separately, probably in the second part I need to specify the source and destination for each node and relations between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use match inside a FOREACH so when you put MERGE and :CONNECT inside the for loop, it is creating multiple nodes.  This is what I did and tell us if it works for you or not.

```
call apoc.load.json("/file.json") yield value
// read the json file
WITH value, value.locations_connections.locations as locs  
// for loop to create the locations (or regions)
FOREACH (loc in locs | MERGE (e:Element {id:loc.id}) ON CREATE
        SET e.longitude = loc.longitude, e.latitude = loc.latitude
)
// get the data for the connections
WITH value.locations_connections.connections as cons  
UNWIND  cons as con
// the keys and value are assigned to variables region and data
WITH KEYS(con)[0] as region_source, con[KEYS(con)[0]] as dat
// unwind is similar to a for loop
UNWIND dat as data
// look for the nodes that we want
MATCH (e1:Element {id: region_source}), (e2:Element {id: data.id})
// create the connection between regions
MERGE (e1)<-[:CONNECT {latency:data.latency, cost:data.cost}]-(e2)
RETURN e1, e2
```

See result below:
[image]